# SparkRDD Operations

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Let's assume i had a table of two columns A and B in a CSV File. I pick maximum value from column A [Max value = 100] and i need to return the respective value of column B [Return Value = AliExpress] using JavaRDD Operations without using DataFrames.

Input Table :

```
COLUMN A     Column B   
   56        Walmart
   72        Flipkart
   96        Amazon
   100       AliExpress
```

Output Table:

```
COLUMN A     Column B   
  100        AliExpress
```

This is what i tried till now

SourceCode:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkCSVReader").setMaster("local");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf); 
JavaRDD<String> diskfile = sc.textFile("/Users/apple/Downloads/Crash_Data_1.csv");
JavaRDD<String> date = diskfile.flatMap(f -> Arrays.asList(f.split(",")[1]));
```

From the above code i can fetch only one column data. Is there anyway to get two columns. Any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `top` or `takeOrdered` functions to achieve it.

```
rdd.top(1)  //gives you top element in your RDD
```

Answer (score 0):

Data:

```
COLUMN_A,Column_B
56,Walmart
72,Flipkart
96,Amazon
100,AliExpress
```

Creating df using **Spark 2**

```
val df = sqlContext.read.option("header", "true")
                   .option("inferSchema", "true")
                   .csv("filelocation")

df.show
import sqlContext.implicits._

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
```

Using Dataframe functions

```
df.orderBy(desc("COLUMN_A")).take(1).foreach(println)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[100,AliExpress]
```

Using RDD functions

```
df.rdd
  .map(row => (row(0).toString.toInt, row(1)))
  .sortByKey(false)
  .take(1).foreach(println)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   (100,AliExpress)
```

Comment: Can you convert this code snippet into java please...

df.rdd
  .map(row => (row(0).toString.toInt, row(1)))
  .sortByKey(false)
  .take(1).foreach(println)